# Rhino JSON.stringify not definied

Tags: javascript, java, json, maven, rhino

I'm trying to print a simple JSON from my javascript using **Rhino 1.7.7.1** from maven.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    Context context = Context.enter();
    try {
        ScriptableObject scope = context.initStandardObjects();
        System.out.println(context.evaluateString(scope, "JSON.stringify({a:1})", null, 1, null));
    } finally {
        Context.exit();
    }
}
```

But I'm got:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "JSON" is not defined. (unnamed script#1)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3654)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3632)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFoundError(ScriptRuntime.java:3717)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.name(ScriptRuntime.java:1692)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1._c0(unnamed script:1)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(unnamed script)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:398)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3065)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(unnamed script)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.exec(unnamed script)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.evaluateString(Context.java:1104)
    at mypackage.RhinoService.main(RhinoService.java:34)
```

Comment: Did you tried with `window.JSON.stringify` ?

Comment: Looks like you might need to teach Rhino about the JSON.stringify method. Google "json stringify polyfill" and try evaluating one of those scripts first.

Answer (score 3):

JSON.stringify is not implemented in the Rhino 1.7 engine. See the [Rhino compatibility table](http://mozilla.github.io/rhino/compat/engines.html).